# Boolean space enveloping an infinite family of Boolean spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I am puzzling over the following problem, which I have been couldn't solve yet.

Suppose we are given an infinite family $\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$ of disjoint Boolean spaces - compact, Hausdorff topological spaces with base of clopen (simultaneously closed and open) subsets (alternatively called Stone spaces).

> Is it always possible to find a Boolean space $S$ containing $\bigcup S_i$; and such that  for each $i\in I$ subsest $S_i\subseteq S$ be a closed subset of $S$?

I have tried to consider a topology on $\bigcup S_i$ generated by $(\bigcup_{k\neq i}S_k)\cup U_j$, where $U_j\in \mathcal O(S_i)$ an open subset of $S_i$, but it is easy to see that in that case we have no $T_2$ separation. Apart that one I have no other ideas yet. Any suggestions, references and any help is appreciated very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  For instance, you can just take $S$ to be the 1-point compactification of the disjoint union $\coprod S_i$.  Or, you could take the coproduct of the $S_i$ in the category of Stone spaces, which is dual to the product $\prod B_i$ of the clopen algebras $B_i$ of each $S_i$.  (This coproduct is in fact the Stone-Cech compactification of the disjoint union $\coprod S_i$, though that takes some work to prove.)

You may find it easier to think about in terms of Boolean algebras.  If $B_i$ is the clopen algebra of $S_i$ and we assume for convenience that we want $\bigcup S_i$ to be dense in $S$, then we're just looking for an $S$ that is the Stone space of a subalgebra $B\subseteq \prod B_i$ with the following properties.  First, the projection of $B$ onto each $B_i$ is surjective (this gives an embedding of each $S_i$ into $S$).  Second, and for each distinct $i,j$, there exists $b\in B$ whose $i$th coordinate is $1$ and $j$th coordinate is $0$ (this means the images of $S_i$ and $S_j$ in $S$ are disjoint).  Alternatively, you can combine these two conditions as the following condition: for each finite $F\subseteq I$, the projection $B\to\prod_F B_i$ is surjective.

The second construction of the first paragraph is given by taking $B$ to just be the full product algebra $\prod B_i$, and the first (the one-point compactification) is given by taking $B$ to be the subalgebra of $\prod B_i$ consisting of elements that are either $0$ on all but finitely many coordinates or $1$ on all but finitely many coordinates.

Comment: Hm, you mean $\beta (\coprod S_i)$ am I right? May be it is easy, but I can not see why should it be zero-dimensional?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the 1-point compactification, not the Stone-Cech compactification.  (The Stone-Cech compactification does work too, though it takes a bit of work to see that it is zero-dimensional.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation in terms of Boolean algebras, I was trying to construct some similar argument but somehow failed to do that :D 
Thank you for quick response.

Comment: One more question along the way, how nice are Vietoris spaces corresponding to the two compactifications?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you very much! Though it was a silly question,  but you have brought the order in my head now.